# How do you spec out your project?

Tags: design, planning, specifications

all. I'm wondering how do you spec./plan out your project? For example, for webiste you can use [Wireframe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Website_wireframe). How about for desktop or add-ins such as MS Office add-ins? I want it as simple as possible and don't want spend all day using some sort of diagram software to sketch it out. Do I simply write down what features I want to build for the software then filter out what is possible and what is not possible? Any tips is appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

The absolute simplest method of 'em all is to whiteboard it and take pictures of what you've done.

Comment: Everyone's got cell phone cameras these days...

Answer (score 1):

### Paper/Pencil

For initial ideas, sketches, basic flow charts.

### Visio

Once I have the ideas down.
I flesh out the methods, flow charts etc. in MS Visio. 
Then I start writing

Answer (score 1):

Wireframes will work for any GUI - it doesn't have to be a web GUI.  I've absolutely used them for client apps in Java using Swing, for example.

I think in general, you need to spec at the level at which you need to communicate.  Since your UI involves both developers and users, you need to spec at a level at which everyone involved can understand.  For a fast, 1-3 man project, that's probably a sketch in a notepad or on a white board.  For a big 20 + person project that's probably:

- initial team brainstorming on a whiteboard
- elaboration with Visio or another tool that will at least draw GUI-looking objects
- Use case elaboration of what happens before, during and after the pictures
- over arching style guides and dictionaries so that as people draw GUIs, the interfaces look alike
- specifications between systems if needed

I'm a big proponent of putting out only as much design as you need.  If you can draw it, have the user feel confident in your solution, and have your team reach a shared understanding of the plan - then you're good.

Comment: +1 for switching media when you have to. No single tool has to do every job...there is significant value in switching fluently between whiteboards, paper, Visio, mockups, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Whiteboard+marker and/or paper and pencil work for me.  I have heard many say so too. It is, in a way, connecting the dots between what is desired and what is existing.